# Is it possible to make a fluid two-column layout in Outlook 2007+ emails

Tags: html, css, email, outlook

I'm coding an email newsletter that must look correct in all email clients, including Outlook 2007+.  One section of the email contains two columns that roughly looks like this:

```
 ----------------------------------------
 |                 |                    |
 |                 |                    |
 |      fluid      |     340px wide     |
 |     content     |         ad         |
 |                 |                    |
 |                 |                    |
 ----------------------------------------
```

The ad in the right column should always be 340px.  The left column should shrink and grow to fill the remaining space.  This is easy to accomplish with a table based layout as long as the screen remains large enough.

However, for smaller screens, such as phones, we need the ad and content to move onto another line, otherwise it forces horizontal scrolling.  We originally accomplished this with floated divs, and a min-width and max-width on the left column.  But this does not work on Outlook as it both ignores the float and reformats the divs, and the only workaround we've found for Outlook's eccentricities is to convert our divs to tables (which won't work in this case).

Is it possible to accomplish what we're trying to accomplish in Outlook 2007+?

The closest I've come is the below, which is not fluid:

```
    <table class="msoFix" width="270" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="left">
        <tr>
            <td width="15">&nbsp;</td>
            <td width="250" align="left" style="padding: 0px; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color:###textColor#; font-size:14px; line-height:16px; font-weight:normal;">
                Content
            </td>
            <td width="5">&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
    </table>

    <table class="msoFix" width="355" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="right">
        <tr>
            <td width="5">&nbsp;</td>
            <td width="345" align="right" style="padding: 0px;">
                Ad
            </td>
            <td width="5">&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

Comment: not sure if this would work but newer things like phones should be browser compatible whereas outlook isn't so you could use media queries to change you tables into block elements for smaller screens (allowing for stacking) and this should be ignored by outlook so you should still have the table layout.  But to make your table fluid, you need to add a width onto every column that is fixed width and then leave the fluid column with no width.  I would also merge the 2 above tables

Comment: [Example fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ttjhtsvm/)

Comment: Pete; that fiddle worked perfectly.  Thanks so much.  Could you please add it as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this would work but newer things like phones should be browser compatible whereas outlook isn't so you could use media queries to change you tables into block elements for smaller screens (allowing for stacking) and this should be ignored by outlook so you should still have the table layout. But to make your table fluid, you need to add a width onto every column that is fixed width and then leave the fluid column with no width. I would also merge the 2 above tables:

```css
@media (max-width: 345px) {
    .msoFix, .msoFix * {
        display:block;
        width:100%;
    }
    .msoFix td.spacer {
        display:none;
    }
}
```

```html
<table class="msoFix" width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="left">
    <tr>
        <td width="15" class="spacer">&nbsp;</td>
        <td align="left" style="padding: 0px; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; background:green; font-size:14px; line-height:16px; font-weight:normal;">Content</td>
        <td width="5" class="spacer">&nbsp;</td>
        <td width="345" align="right" style="padding: 0px; background:blue;">Ad</td>
        <td width="5" class="spacer">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

[Example Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ttjhtsvm/)

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible, you can use media queries for mobile as they can read them...

It would look like this.

```css
@media max-width(380px) {
  table[class=left-column],
  table[class=right-column] {
    width: 100% !important;
  }
}
```

```html
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tr>
    <th scope="col">&nbsp;</th>
    <th scope="col">&nbsp;</th>
    <th scope="col">&nbsp;</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="3">
      
      <!-- give the tables a class then  use a media query for mobiles -->
      <!-- I've found that using 2-3% less than 100% width removes possible errors in outlook -->
      
      <table width="32%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="left" class="left-column">
        <tr>
          <td width="15">&nbsp;</td>
          <td width="250" align="left" style="padding: 0px; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color:###textColor#; font-size:14px; line-height:16px; font-weight:normal;">
            Content
          </td>
          <td width="5">&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
      </table>

      <table width="65%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="right" class="right-column">
        <tr>
          <td width="5">&nbsp;</td>
          <td width="345" align="right" style="padding: 0px;">
            Ad <!-- set the ad to 100% width -->
          </td>
          <td width="5">&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

css-tricks has a good article on responsive columns in emails. https://css-tricks.com/ideas-behind-responsive-emails/

Comment: Thank you for the response.  I tried this, but my native Android email app appeared to ignore the media queries and render the tables at their percentage widths.  This still results in them appearing stacked on two lines, but each only takes a small portion of that line.  This also does not make the first column fluid as it still has a fixed width.